# Excel - Locked for editing by ' '

Tags: networking, microsoft-excel-2003

I am trying to open a file on a network share, when it is already in use Excel tells me :

```
<file> is locked for editing

by ' '.
```

Then offers to let me open it as read only.

My question is where is Excel getting (or not getting) the user name, the users log into a windows domain (samba) with unique user ids and they all have user names defined in their local copies of Excel.

Till about a month ago Excel was returning the correct user name.

Comment: It's been locked by a ninja.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Ninjas, again!  They're worse than the mice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got this from a [source](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/126657-excel-2007-file-locked-for-editing-by):

> If I recall correctly, the "user name" is actually the name set in the
>   Excel Options, rather than the actual user that's logged on.
>
> As such, it could quite easily be any old rubbish.
>
> Have you checked the open files on the share to find out if anyone
>   really has it open?

A possible cause ([source](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=749302)):

> When Excel opens a file it creates a temporary
>   copy of the file, and then as you work with it it makes changes to
>   that file.  When you save the file it then deletes the original,
>   replaces with the temp file and delets the temp file.  If the machine
>   or app crashes before this happens you can get stuck with the temp
>   file nor being deleted.  Next time you open the file, Excel will
>   attempt to create a temp file and realise that one is already there,
>   hence the message that the file is already open.
>
> Try deleting all files in the temp directories on both his machine and
>   the server (may have to reboot).

If you want to open it without knowing who has it, check these methods:

> 1. Go to Computer Management where Shared Folders may help. Open a run box, type Compmgmt.msc, then go to Shared Folders and look at Open
>      Files.
> 2. Try the NET FILE command. Open a run box, type CMD to open a command prompt. At the prompt, type NET FILE. It will show any remote
>      users with files open on the current machine.
> 3. If those 2 methods fail, go here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655
>
> This SysInternal tool will show you any process that is locking a
>   file. This is your answer if the other two simpler methods dont turn
>   up any leads.

Comment: Thanks, I did find that page and I checked the User name in Excel options of the person who is locking it and it is set correctly.  The file is definitely open, the file is shared on a linux server so the three suggestions don't apply.

Comment: @Tim: `smbstatus` should work, then.

Comment: @grawity `smbstatus` does work but it is more of a windows UI display niggle, the windows users can't see who has locked it even though `smbstatus` confirms that it is locked and who locked it.

Comment: @TimtheEnchanter: so, you still can't unlock the sheet or is there another issue?

Comment: @djerry it is just the dialogue that the users see is completely unhelpful because it shews blank, the locking works apart from that.

Comment: @TimtheEnchanter: I've edited my answer and added a possible cause to this problem. Maybe that can explain why it happened.